# Заглавная или строчная в наименованиях документов?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Как пишутся в русском языке наименование документов после двоеточия - с заглавной или строчной, например Календарный план?

Comment: А можно предложение поподробнее  написать? Что еще предполагается, кроме этих двух слов?

Comment: Не надо ставить теги от балды. Вы в курсе, что такое синтаксис? Какое он имеет отношение к прописным и строчным буквам?  
Исправила на "орфографию".

Answer (score 3):

> Разработаны: после двоеточия всегда пишут с маленькой буквы Календарный план выполнения мероприятий на мирное время;

Здесь неверно все. Фразу как таковую без посторонних слов можете написать?
Если так:

***Разработаны: календарный план выполнения мероприятий на мирное время,...***

То оснований для заглавной тут нет. Точка с запятой тоже излишняя. Иногда, правда, таким образом оформляют списки, в которых каждый элемент идет с новой строки. Это не регламентируется правилами правописания, т.е. можно рассматривать как типографский прием.

Answer (score 2):

Календарный план - это не название документа, а тип и пишется со строчной буквы. Исключением является тот случай, когда наименование даётся уже в самом тексте документа, фразой вроде *"календарный план на 2013 год (далее Календарный план)"*.  Если выше по тексту календарному плану и другим документам наименования не даны, то пишется со строчной буквы (как вариант - полное наименование документа с заглавной, но в кавычках).  Если даны, то по правилам имён собственных - с заглавной.

Comment: Разработаны: после двоеточия всегда пишут с маленькой буквы
Календарный план выполнения мероприятий на мирное время;



Всегда или здесь все таки с большой?

Comment: В данном случае наименование. Так с заглавной:=?

Comment: @Аманбек, в данном случае, можно с заглавной, но в кавычках, так как тут название документа. Если без кавычек - то всё со строчной.

И не нужно плодить вопросы, можно отредактировать этот.